# how get calc saturday+monday in range date

Tags: php

i hope some help to me ...
 i am trouble with some code IN PHP ,maybe you can see function about this :

I need to check is there on Saturday in one period ($date_start ,$date_end )
so :
 input : $date_Start (ex:  "2010-07-01")
         $date_end   (ex:  "2010-07-12")

output : total saturday : 2 in your range date

but the way thanks before

JOKONARDI

Answer (score 0):

Efficient implementation with no loops for number of Saturdays in the range:

```
$d1 = new DateTime("2010-07-01"); //including
$d2 = new DateTime("2010-07-12"); //excluding
$diff = $d2->diff($d1);
$days = $diff->format("%a");
$num = floor($days / 7);
$remaining = $days % 7;
$d = $d1->format("w");
if ($d + $remaining > 6)
    $num++;

//result in $num
```

Comment: thanks friend.. nice solution and this is top site for reference for me :)

Comment: but i am so sorry ,result $num = 859
actually ,value = 2

Comment: hm...maybe can you give me some function diff  ?
i read your code using this :
diff($d1)

Comment: my result now NAN 
this is my code :
<?php

$d1 = new DateTime("2010-07-01"); //including
$d2 = new DateTime("2010-07-12"); //excluding
$diff = $d2->diff($d1);
$days = $diff->format("%a");
$num = floor($days / 7);
$remaining = $days % 7;
$d = $d1->format("w");
if ($d + $remaining > 6) {
    $num++;
}
echo"$num";
?>